# An unexpected error has occurred, When Releasing Android App

Tags: android, apk, release

All,

We are trying to release Android app in Android Developer console, We have complete the store listing part and trying to uploading the app under Launch section.

Under Launch section --> Production -- > Create new release, It is showing progress bar and throwing a error "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (722125BA) " And nothing happens from here,

We are trying from yesterday, Deleted Browser cache and cookies, Still facing the issue.

What steps we have to follow, Do we need to add any content.

Comment: Never seen this before. Maybe try a different browser? Or an incognito window without browser extensions? If that also doesn't help, I would contact Google support about it, stating what you have already tried.

Comment: I have tried Chrome incognito window, Trying from different systems, In all systems we have the same issue